# Performance issue on operations involving pandas dataframes

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a panda dataframe containing OHLC 1mn data. (19724 rows). I am looking at adding 2 new columns keeping tracks of the min price and the maximum price over the past 3 days (including today up to the current bar in question, and ignoring missing days). However I am running into performance issues as a %timeit of the for loop indicates 57 seconds... I am looking at ways to speed up (vectorization? I tried but I am struggling a little bit I must admit).

```
#Import the data and put them in a DataFrame. The DataFrame should contain
#the following fields: DateTime (the index), Open, Close, High, Low, Volume.

#----------------------
#The following assume the first column of the file is Datetime
dfData=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(DataLocation,FileName),index_col='Date')
dfData.index=pd.to_datetime(dfData.index,dayfirst=True)
dfData.index.tz_localize('Singapore')

# Calculate the list of unique dates in the dataframe to find T-2
ListOfDates=pd.to_datetime(dfData.index.date).unique()

#Add a ExtMin and and ExtMax to the dataFrame to keep track of the min and max over a certain window
dfData['ExtMin']=np.nan
dfData['ExtMax']=np.nan

#For each line in the dataframe, calculate the minimum price reached over the past 3 days including today.

def addMaxMin(dfData):
    for index,row in dfData.iterrows():
        #Find the index in ListOfDates, strip out the time, offset by -2 rows
        Start=ListOfDates[max(0,ListOfDates.get_loc(index.date())-2)]
        #Populate the ExtMin and ExtMax columns
        dfData.ix[index,'ExtMin']=dfData[(Start<=dfData.index) & (dfData.index<index)]['LOW'].min()
        dfData.ix[index,'ExtMax']=dfData[(Start<=dfData.index) & (dfData.index<index)]['HIGH'].max()
    return dfData

%timeit addMaxMin(dfData)
```

Thanks.